# How to create a dict from another dict by filtering some items?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary `dict1` which looks like,

```
dict1 = {'key1':'val1', 'key2':'val2', 'key3':'val3'}
```

Now, I want to create a new dictionary `dict2` based on `dict1`, but without key:val pair for `key1`, so `dict2` is like,

```
dict2 = {'key2':'val2', 'key3':'val3'}
```

I am wondering what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to exclude that specific key:

```
dict2 = {k: v for k, v in dict1.items() if k != 'key1'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>import copy
>>dict2 = copy.copy(dict1)
>>dict2.pop("key1")
'val1'
>>dict2
{'key2': 'val2', 'key3': 'val3'}
```